# Associate a list to other class MVC (LINQ?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two classes, Classroom and Schedule. A Classroom have a list of Schedules:

```
public class Classroom
{
    public int ClassroomId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
}

 public class Schedule
{
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }

    public string Entry { get; set; }
    public string Exit { get; set; }

    public string ClassroomId { get; set; }
    public Classroom Classroom { get; set; }
}
```

Then i wanted to show in a View all the schedules that are associated to a classroom. I thought of using LINQ but i don't see how can i use it when i want a list of schedules and not only one schedule.
Can someone help me? Or maybe tell me other way to do this?
Thank you

btw i'm using MVC 4 but i can also use MVC 5

Comment: yes i am using it @StephenMuecke

Comment: `Classroom model = db.Classrooms.Where(c => c.ClassroomId == someID).Include("Schedules ").FirstOrDefault();` and make the `Schedules` virtual (see also Farhad Jabiyev's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework, then you must use `virtual` property for marking `Schedules` and `Classroom` properties as navigation property. A navigation property allows you to navigate from one entity to a "connected" entity.

In `Classrrom` implementation:

```
public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
```

In `Schedule` implementation:

```
public virtual Classroom Classroom { get; set; }
```

Then enable `LazyLoading` if you have manually disabled it.
After this you can use:

```
var classroom = db.Classrooms.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClassroomId == clasroomId); // fetch it from the database
var schedules = classroom.Schedules.ToList(); // It will fetch all schedules associated with that classroom
```

By the way, in the previous method you will send two different queries to the database. If you don't want this for some reason, you can use `Include()` method to load `Schedules` eagerly. In this case, `Join` query will be sent to the database.

Then it will be as:

```
var schedules = db.Classrooms
    .Include(x => x.Schedules)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClassroomId == clasroomId)
    .Select(x => x.Schedules)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm having a error in the last classroomId ((x => x.ClassroomId == clasroomId)). I was putting this code in the controller ClassroomController in public ActionResult Details(int id = 0) in order to show the schedules of that certain classroom in the view details. But i don't know if i can do this or if i'm putting in the right place. (Sorry, newbie here). Can you or someone help me in this?

Comment: @dasdasd Not problem, I will help you. I have just tried to guess the variable name. You can change it to `id` if your input's name is `id`.

Comment: Thank you it worked now but how do i edit the view in order to show the classrooms schedule? I have this in the controller: 

public ActionResult Details(int id = 0) { 
Classroom classroom = db.Classrooms.Find(id);
            if (classroom == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
var classroomx = db.Classrooms.FirstOrDefault(x => x.classroomId == id); 
var schedules= x.Schedules.ToList(); 
return View(classroom); 
}

Comment: And the view:

model Project.Models.Classroom

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Classroom</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.ClassroomId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>

Comment: @dasdasd It is different question, and it will be better to ask it in s new question. First of all mark the answer as accepted if that really helped you :) and then ask your new question. You will get more explained answer in that way. Good luck.